# References/Proof of the conjectured identity for the Stirling permutation number $\left\{{n\atop n-k}\right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers, eulerian-numbers

While working with a combinatorics problem, I conjectured that

$$ \left\{{n \atop n-k }\right\}=\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\bigg\langle\!\!\bigg\langle{k\atop k-1-p}\bigg\rangle\!\!\bigg\rangle \binom{n+p}{2k}, $$

where $\left\{ {n \atop k} \right\}$ is the [*Stirling permutation numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and  $\big\langle\!\big\langle{n \atop k}\big\rangle\!\big\rangle $ denotes the [*Eulerian numbers of the second kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

- All of my motivation comes from the fact that this is known to hold for $k = 1, 2, 3$. (See [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Particular_Values_of_Stirling_Numbers_of_the_Second_Kind#Stirling_Number_of_the_Second_Kind:_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ-MathJax-7-QINU.60.22.27.7F), for instance.)
- I have little background on this topic, and I was unable to find this one from [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8).
- I numerically checked that this identity holds for $n = 1, \cdots, 10$ using CAS and [OEIS A008517](https://oeis.org/A008517/table).

Although I hardly believe that this type of identity is not known, I could not find any proof or reference to this one. So any additional information will be appreciated!

Comment: Given that you've got an '$n-p$' term multiplied by a '$p$' term, your sum looks like a convolution of appropriate terms, and so should be straightforwardly writeable as a product of generating functions; that's absolutely the first axis I would explore along.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Nice point! I will definitely try that.

Comment: I've just posted an induction proof for this formula as well as its twin formula for the Stirling cycle numbers, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4814252/61691

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Concrete Mathematics (what else?) - Eulerian Numbers" - says:
"[Second-order Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_kind) are important chiefly because of their connection with Stirling numbers"

Eq. (6.43) therein gives
$$
\left\{ \matrix{  x \cr x - n \cr}  \right\}
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle } \binom{x+n-1-k}{2n}
\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;x \in C \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which easily reduce to yours, and can be extended to define Stirling No. of 2nd kind, of the indicated form, 
to complex values of $x$.

Interestingly,  also given is a twin one for the Stirling No. of 1st kind
$$
\left[ \matrix{  x \cr   x - n \cr}  \right] 
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{
  n \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle } \binom{x+k}{2n}
  \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;x \in C \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Comment: Concrete Mathematics also hints at an inductive proof of these identities. I just posted a question asking for the details of the inductive proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813419/61691